How to prevent an INSTEAD OF trigger from firing until another INSTEAD OF trigger has completed
I'm working on a project where two applications read/write the same tables. Neither application can be changed. One is written in Access, the other in .NET and will be replacing the Access application and therefore 'owns' the table schema.
Table schema is like this:
Prosecution:
CustomerID 
ProsecutionID

Charges:
CustomerID 
ProsecutionID
ChargeID

ChargeDetail:
CustomerID 
ChargeID

EDIT: CustomerID was edited to remove (PK)
The Access application does not write the CustomerID so I use an INSTEAD OF trigger on the Charges table to lookup the CustomerID from Prosecution.
SET @CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID 
                   FROM Prosecution 
                   WHERE ProsecutionID = ProsecutionID 
                   FROM INSERTED) 

On the ChargeDetail table I have an INSTEAD OF trigger that needs to look up the CustomerID using
SET @CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID  
                   FROM Charges 
                   WHERE ChargeID = ChargeID 
                   FROM INSERTED)

If I update and save the charges part of the Access form first it works fine. The issue is that the form in Access for Charges and ChargeDetail in one one form and when submitted with data in both areas causes the ChargeDetail trigger to fire first and fails with a PK violation because Charges hasn't been written yet.
Long preamble to my questions:
What is the best way to make the trigger on ChargeDetail "wait" for the other trigger to complete?
I could put a WHILE loop in the trigger that checks for the write to the other table to complete, but that sounds dangerous. How could I force a WHILE loop to exit in the case the write to Charges table fails for any reason?
Is there anyway the trigger could confirm completion of the other trigger via SQL Server?

You can't. You need to change your logic... Can you maybe update both tables from the trigger that runs last?

That said, why have a de-normalised design anyway, you shouldn't store the same data in multiple tables if you can access it via a lookup. Just stop writing the customerid and query it instead.

Isn't access single threaded, so the insert to Charge will happen after insert of ChargeDetail and putting a delay will just lead to a halt. A hacky workaround (although probably less hacky than your current system) would be to save a negative ChargeID value into ChargeDetail.CustomerID, and then update it inside the Charge-trigger to correct value

Or update it into a new, temp column with no FK and then update it into the correct column in the other trigger... all hacky, all un-necessary if you don't dup the data.

@DaleK - I can't alter the application code or schema.  ````CustomerID``` is a PK in all tables so I can't leave it blank and fix it later.

@siggemannen Haven't figured out yet why Access writes ChargeDetail first. Usually there is an AfterUpdate event in Access but I haven't found it (yet). I like the idea of writing a dummy value for CustomerID, I'll look into modifying the Charge table trigger or possibly adding an AFTER trigger to fix CustomerID.

Weird that CustomerId is your PK, because that means you can only have one of each record per Customer - which doesn't match with how I would understand the scheme. I guess as siggemannen says you can set it to the wrong CustomerId in the first trigger and correct it in the second. All hacks of course which may raise other issues.

@DaleK - Good catch, I should not have shown CustomerID as PK on its own. It is half of the table PK along with another field (not shown) that is sequential and unique (like an IDENTITY column) but maintained by the application. I'm going to try @siggemannen suggestion of writing a place holder value and then adding an AFTER trigger to update with the correct CustomerID value. Thanks for you help.

Aside: If you are going to use triggers that can only handle a single row in inserted and/or deleted then add some code to check the number of rows and throw a fit if it isn't 1.

Good point ☝️ triggers inherently run on sets of rows (including zero), so you should write your trigger to handle a set, or otherwise as suggested throw an error if the number of rows isn't 1.

If, on the insert to charge details, you note that CustomerID is missing, you should be able to assign a number from a particular range that you think CustomerID is unlikely to reach, then with the insert of into Charges, update that number with the actual number.
Here is an example:
Representative Tables:
CREATE TABLE Q79238426.Prosecution (
    PK INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    ProsecutionID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Prosecution PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PK, CustomerId)
)


CREATE TABLE Q79238426.Charges(
    PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    ProsecutionID INT NOT NULL,
    ChargeID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Charges PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PK, CustomerId)
)

CREATE TABLE Q79238426.ChargeDetail(
    PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    ChargeID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ChargeDetail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PK, CustomerId)
)

A Sequence to provide number in a known range:
/* Sequence to provide known replacable "temp" CustomerIds*/
CREATE SEQUENCE Q79238426.TempCustomerId AS INT START WITH 1000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE   1999999999  NO CYCLE

Triggers to replace values as needed:
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER  Q79238426.InsteadOf_Charges_Insert
ON Q79238426.Charges
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON

/* If a CustomerId was not passed, fill from Prosecution */
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE CustomerId IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    
    /* Note: assuming an all or nothing on CustomerId */
    INSERT INTO Q79238426.Charges(CustomerId, ProsecutionID, ChargeID)
    SELECT p.CustomerID, i.ProsecutionID, i.ChargeId
    FROM inserted i
        JOIN Q79238426.Prosecution p on i.ProsecutionID = p.ProsecutionID
END     
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO Q79238426.Charges(CustomerId, ProsecutionID, ChargeID)
    SELECT CustomerId, ProsecutionID, ChargeID 
    FROM inserted

/* If there are any ChargeDetails with tempCustomerIds, update them based upon this insert */
UPDATE cd
SET CustomerId = i.CustomerId
FROM Q79238426.ChargeDetail cd
    JOIN inserted i ON i.ChargeId = cd.ChargeId AND cd.CustomerId >= 1000000000


GO


CREATE  TRIGGER  Q79238426.InsteadOf_ChargeDetail_Insert
ON Q79238426.ChargeDetail
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE CustomerId IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    /* Use Customer from Charge when available, if not supplied */
    SELECT ISNULL(i.CustomerId, c.CustomerId) CustomerId, i.ChargeId
    INTO #insert
    FROM inserted i
        LEFT JOIN Q79238426.Charges c on i.ChargeID = c.ChargeID

    /* Assign tempCustomerIds for any that still need it.  
        Note: is separate due to limitation is NEXT VALUE FOR; no case, coalesce, isnull allowed*/
    UPDATE #insert
    SET CustomerId = NEXT VALUE FOR Q79238426.TempCustomerId
    WHERE CustomerID IS NULL

    INSERT INTO Q79238426.ChargeDetail (CustomerId, ChargeId)
    SELECT CustomerId, ChargeId
    FROM #insert

END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Q79238426.ChargeDetail (CustomerId, ChargeId)
    SELECT CustomerId, ChargeId FROM inserted

Insert Some Data to Test, noting the difference in order:
INSERT INTO Q79238426.Prosecution(CustomerId, ProsecutionID) VALUES (10000, 10001)
INSERT INTO Q79238426.Charges(ProsecutionID, ChargeID) VALUES (10001, 10002)
INSERT INTO Q79238426.ChargeDetail(ChargeId) VALUES (10002)

INSERT INTO Q79238426.Prosecution(CustomerId, ProsecutionID) VALUES (20000, 20001)
INSERT INTO Q79238426.ChargeDetail(ChargeId) VALUES (20002)
INSERT INTO Q79238426.Charges(ProsecutionID, ChargeID) VALUES (20001, 20002)

Confirm Output:
SELECT * FROM Q79238426.Prosecution 
SELECT * FROM Q79238426.Charges 
SELECT * FROM Q79238426.ChargeDetail 

Results:
PK          CustomerId  ProsecutionID
----------- ----------- -------------
1           10000       10001
2           20000       20001

(2 rows affected)

PK          CustomerId  ProsecutionID ChargeID
----------- ----------- ------------- -----------
1           10000       10001         10002
2           20000       20001         20002

(2 rows affected)

PK          CustomerId  ChargeID
----------- ----------- -----------
1           10000       10002
2           20000       20002

(2 rows affected)

